# FFmpeg image2pipe write buffer wait until done

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process

I'm extracting frames from an external source and passing it in as a buffer to FFMPEG using `image2pipe` and `-i -`

```
const childProcess = spawn(ffmpeg, [
  "-y",
  "-f",
  "image2pipe",
  "-i",
  "-",
  "-vcodec",
  "libx264",
  "-pix_fmt",
  "yuv420p",
  output
]);
```

Then I have a loop that does the job.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
  // ...await
}
```

Inside the promise

```
// ... do the job to get buffer

childProcess.stdin.write(frame); // frame === buffer

// frame done
resolve("success!");
```

The problem is in some videos the frames jump and is janky. This is because FFmpeg is not fully done writing to the file before moving onto the next frame.

Is there a way to write a buffer to a file through FFmpeg and make sure the frame is done writing before moving on?

Some more information

Here is the source file https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.v2.uploads/ckigi4kro00160vlfjmt74afp

Here is the rendered file https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/storycreator.testing/607715f0-3ab9-11eb-a139-3bb84618c6c5.mp4?t=1607585343922

Here are logs

```
2020-12-10T07:28:48.942Z    0ae0c435-54d3-416f-9d1a-8ddf595a7e83    INFO    frame=  130 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=      83kB time=00:00:05.08 bitrate= 133.6kbits/s speed=0.641x    video:80kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.928688%
```

```
2020-12-10T07:28:48.942Z    0ae0c435-54d3-416f-9d1a-8ddf595a7e83    INFO    [libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:15.47  size: 68227[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] frame P:33    Avg QP:15.07  size:   246[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] frame B:96    Avg QP:18.75  size:    56[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] consecutive B-frames:  1.5%  0.0%  0.0% 98.5%
```

```
2020-12-10T07:28:48.943Z    0ae0c435-54d3-416f-9d1a-8ddf595a7e83    INFO    [libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] mb I  I16..4: 24.6% 60.5% 14.9%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.2%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.9%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:26.7% L1:73.3% BI: 0.0%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] 8x8 transform intra:62.0% inter:83.6%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 49.2% 44.3% 32.1% inter: 0.0% 0.2% 0.0%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 53% 38%  7%  2%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 24% 29%  3%  3%  3%  5%  3%  4%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 26% 14%  3%  4%  5%  4%  4%  3%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 27% 13%  3%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] ref P L0: 95.1%  1.2%  3.1%  0.6%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] ref B L0: 48.1% 51.3%  0.7%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] ref B L1: 97.3%  2.7%[libx264 @ 0x640d6c0] kb/s:125.75
```

```
2020-12-10T07:28:48.944Z    0ae0c435-54d3-416f-9d1a-8ddf595a7e83    INFO    [cache @ 0x5f57940] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:3551
```

Comment: Try the async and cache protocol as shown here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#async

Comment: Is there a more elaborate example of using this protocol. I don't quite understand how to implement it. Cant find much on Google, I did read the top of the page. Do I prefix my output with `async:`? If so how do I handle it such that the frame interpolation is in order

Comment: Replace `"-"` with `"async:cache:pipe:0"`

Comment: Interesting and that's it? Ffmpeg will order the frames accordingly? If so that is awesome

Comment: The frames were still jank without the artificial delay. Am I missing something

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Share full ffmpeg log and maybe some screenshots of source and result.

Comment: Ok fair enough. In the OP I added the source video, the rendered video, and some logs. Happy to add additional info. I see in the logs this seems off `frame=  130 fps= 16` 16 fps seems wrong. Should I specify the fps?

Comment: Your sys isn't able to encode fast enough OR frames aren't arriving fast enough. If the former, adding `-preset ultrafast` will help.

Comment: Yeah it's inside Lambda. I think it's the later because the frames are in puppeteer (Chromium) and screenshotted to a buffer asynchronously per frame.

Comment: Any thoughts on this matter?